# Splitting Dataset over Multiple GPUs

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

I'm training a large network that inputs and outputs 512x512 images. At the moment, I have 2 Tesla A100 GPUs with 40 GB of memory each, and a dataset comprising 10,000 input and outputs pairs. This adds up to roughly 38 GB of training data, which leads me to run out of memory when sending this data to the "cuda" device to create my dataset. I am simply using DataParallel to distribute the training.

How can I split my dataset up over the two GPUs to avoid running out of memory?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. Open to others, especially more memory-efficient options!

```
to_t = lambda array: torch.tensor(array, device=device)

class CustomDataset(Dataset):
def __init__(self, image, label):
    self.image = image
    self.label = label

def __len__(self):
    return len(self.label)

def __getitem__(self, idx):
    image = self.image[idx]
    label = self.label[idx]
    return to_t(image).float(), to_t(label).float()
```